# Aptana 3.1.1 (17th April 2012) Doesn't track changes using Git

Tags: php, git, aptana

I have been using Aptana Studio 3 for some time now and I make heavy use of the Git features.

Since upgrading today (17th April 2012) Aptana is not tracking my changes anymore.

Normally when I change any of my files the file name  background turns red, and an asterix appears next to it letting me know the file has changed and needs to be staged / committed.

Things I have tried:

- Searched aptana bugs.
- Searched through the preferences.
- Reverting back to a previous configuration.
- Restarting my pc.
- Checked the .git folder is still there (yes).
- Created a new project and pull all files down to a new folder (doesn't help)

Does anyone know how I can re-enable this feature (if the update changed any settings) or has the update changed the way the files are tracked?

Additional Info: The more I use this version of Aptana the more I find has been broken. I think I'll just file a bug report titled Version 3.1.1

Thanks for the suggestions anyway guys.

More Info:

After hours of searching google for anything related to this I decided to unistall Aptana, manually searched for any remaining preference files created by the previous install and removed them, grabbed the previous release 3.1, reinstalled that version, created a new git repo and pull the files down to my new folder. What a total waste of time it's been today <strike>pissing</strike> messing about with Aptana!

Comment: Is your git repo still there? Is there is a `.git` directory where our sources are?

Comment: Yep, I should mention that if I restart Aptana, it picks up all the changes and everything is highlighted and I can use the stage / commit shortcuts. But this isn't ideal.

Comment: Did you press F5 or similar to refresh the view? Have you waited a bit until the icons appear? Maybe icons changed to `>` symbols?

Comment: I've tried refreshing the view yes, unfortunately it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same bug here. I created new issue for it: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4663

[Chris Williams](https://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=cwilliams) comments on the Jira ticket:

> After a little research reproducing this:
>   This doesn't happen on Mac, and on Windows the IDE is picking up the file events from outside the IDE - but the git support is not properly "reacting" to them.
>   My guess is that the listener that forces refreshes of the git status on changes is breaking due to some path issue (we take the path of the changed file, then try to find the corresponding file from a relative path in the git repo, and then update our git status for it if it's under the repo - it's probably not generating that relative path properly).
>
> **Found I was using improper implementations of generating repo relative paths in a couple locations, rather than using the correct one available in `GitRepository.repoRelativePath()`.
>
>   Replacing them with calls to that should fix this issue for Windows users.**
>
> Fix Version/s:
>
> - Sprint 2012-08 (craterlake),
> - Aptana Studio 3.1.2,
> - Aptana Studio 3.1.3

So hopefully, there is progress.

Comment: Nice one fella, I think it might be something to do with the path to the git executable, now I've had some time to reflect. I use Git-Bash here and I believe the update may have changed Aptana's path to it's built in portable-git that it uses.

Comment: +1 for actually creating the bug report though, don't take this the wrong way, but I am so glad I am not alone with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

same Problem here (aptana on Windows). 
For me it starts with an update of egit to lastest Version 1.3.0.201202151440

As i need this version, i cant go back. Maybe someone with this problem, can go back to an older version of egit

PS: actually all file changes are show if i start the command : Team -> status 
and if i restart aptana, the changed files can be staged and commited ... 
so i have to restart aptana some times each day ..